# Canonical transformations: Time derivative of generating function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Consider a canonical transformartion $(p,q) \rightarrow (P,Q)$ with type-2 generating function. How can I show,
$$\frac{\partial{\Phi}}{\partial{t}}=-\sum_{i} P_i \frac{\partial{Q_i}}{\partial{t}} + \frac{\partial{F_2}}{\partial{t}}$$
knowing that
$$F_2(q,Q,t)=\Phi(q,p(q,Q,t),t)$$
well, i tried to use the chain rule, but i'm not sure how to treat the $q$'s and $Q$'s, because, as far as i know, $q=q(t)$ and $Q=Q(p,q,t)$. I'm aware of the 'equations of motion' for type-2 generating functions. The main problem is to relate the derivative of $\Phi$ with that of $F_2$

Any tips will be aprecciated.

Comment: If you write your attempt at doing the chain rule in your question, it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: @N.Steinle i'm sorry for not writing it, but all I did was taking the total derivate of $\Phi$ and $F_2$ and tried comparing them. It was not that helpful

Comment: @Qmechanic yea, N. A. Lemos. Analytical mechanics. pg. 275 problem 8.1

Comment: In the English translation from 2018 it is problem 8.1 at the end of chap. 8 on p. 281. And it is a type-1 CT, not a type-2 CT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a Hint:

Canonical transform generated by $F_2(q,Q,t)$ give
$$p=\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial q} \ \\ \ \ \ \\ P=-\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial Q}$$

Consider a legendre transform to $\Phi(q,p,t)$ from $F_2(q,Q,t)$

$$F_2(q,Q,t)=\Phi(q,p,t)+Qp$$
That's all. From here Take the total derivative of both hand sides and use the fact that $Q=Q(q,p,t)$ and then use the derivative of the generating function. Equate the time derivative terms from both hand side. That's will prove the identity.

Comment: It's rather a simple method than a laborious chain rule.

Comment: so in this case $q$ and $p$ only depend on time?